# Google Spreadsheet: "Authorisation needed" when clicking button

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, authorization

I made a script that should insert two new rows in Google spreadsheets and copy paste the layout and values of two other rows.
But when I press the button I get a pop up window with "authorisation needed" and can't seem to fix it.

[image: spreadsheetbutton]

[image: spreadsheetbuttonA]

and this is the script that it should run:

```html
function DuplicateSelectedRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //spreadsheet.getRange('B:B').activate();
 // spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('A1'));

  //Insert rows before last training (row B and C) 
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getColumn(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 1).activate();
  
  // merge cells top
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2:C2').activate()
  .mergeAcross();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:C3').activate()
  .mergeAcross();
  
  //spreadsheet.getRangeList(['B:B', 'C:C']).activate();
  //spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('A1'));
  //spreadsheet.getRange('B4:C20').activate();
  
  //paste values in newly created rows
  spreadsheet.getRange('D4:E20').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3:C3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3:E3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2:C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2:E2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

Comment: did you authorize your script? if not, then you need to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- go back to the script editor and press run button (triangle-shaped button)
- popup window will show up asking you to authorize the script for your spreadsheet
- continue and ignore all warnings
- when you finished authorizing your script go back to your spreadsheet and press your button

Comment: thanks! that worked!
well my script doesn't, but the popup is gone :D now i can start debugging